# Delete rows having duplicate entries in R

Tags: r, delete-row

```
    Id TimeToEnd DistanceToRadar Composite HybridScan HydrometeorType Kdp RR1
 1:  1        56              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 2:  1        37              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 3:  1        31              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 4:  1        25              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 5:  1        19              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 6:  1        13              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 7:  1         7              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 8:  1         2              30    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
 9:  2        58              77    -99900     -99900               8   0   0
10:  2        48              77    -99900     -99900               8   0   0

    TimeToEndInversion NewDistanceToRadar NewRadarIndicator RadarSeries
 1:                  1                  1              TRUE           1
 2:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 3:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 4:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 5:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 6:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 7:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 8:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
 9:                  1                  1              TRUE           1
10:                  0                  0             FALSE           1
         Mean
 1: 11.125000
 2: 11.125000
 3: 11.125000
 4: 11.125000
 5: 11.125000
 6: 11.125000
 7: 11.125000
 8: 11.125000
 9:  7.416667
10:  7.416667
```

For the above data, I wish to have rows with unique Mean for groups of Id and RadarSeries, I tried

> head(dtt[,unique(Mean),by=c("Id","RadarSeries")])
>        but this gives,

```
Id RadarSeries        V1
1:  1           1 11.125000
2:  2           1  7.416667
3:  3           1  5.250000
4:  4           1 12.750000
5:  5           1 15.000000
6:  5           2 21.916667
```

whereas I want every column to be in the resulting data table and not just Id,RadarSeries and Mean. Any Idea

> how to do this ?
>   Edit : I want max() of remaining columns.

Comment: So, in your data the first 8 rows have the same Id, RadarSeries, and Mean, so you want them to be collapsed to one row. They have different values of `TimeToEnd`, `TimeToEndInversion`, `NewDistanceToRadar` and `NewRadarIndicator`. For these varying columns what do you want, the first value? last value? average? random sample? something else?

Comment: In general, in data manipulation, when you summarize data this way, every single variable needs to be either part of your grouping (e.g. Id and RadarSeries) or part of an aggregate function that takes a lot of values as input but only outputs one (like `mean`, `first()`, `last()`, `sum()`...).

Comment: ohk..thanks. I didn't notice this. Now i have to think for it.

Comment: Fine..if I want max() of remaining columns, how do I write it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
dtt %>% group_by(Id, RadarSeries, Mean) %>%
    summarize_each(funs(max))
```